# Redis client not connecting using the redis module in Node

Tags: node.js, redis

I have the following code to make a simple connection to a local redis instance on the default redis port. I have followed https://redis.io/docs/clients/nodejs/ redis official docs, but with minor changes.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Error encountered: ', error);
});

(async() => {
    await client.connect();
})();

client.set('key', 'value');
```

When I run it, it seems to hang and when I check with redis-cli, the database doesn't get populated. If I add an await to the client.set, I get the error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

I am unsure how I am supposed to continue or where my misunderstanding is at

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I see the value is set in Redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get key
"value"
```

The reason why your script doesn't quit is because you aren't closing the connection.  You can do this with `client.quit()` after your set completes.

I'd recommend refactoring to use top level await if you can (set `"type": "module"`) in `package.json`) then you can do this:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

await client.connect();
await client.set('key', 'value');
await client.quit();
```

and your `package.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^4.6.6"
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use a module / import / top level await try this:

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient();

(async() => {
  await client.connect();
  await client.set('key', 'value');
  await client.quit();
})();
```

with `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^4.6.6"
  }
}
```